# Is the BS170 MOSFET the right candidate for the task?

Tags: mosfet, jfet, integrator

[image: BS170]

[image]

I have 2 FETs in my arsenal, the BF256 and the BS170 and I want to reset an opamp integrator.

Is the BS170 the right part for the task? The datasheet doesn't tell a lot, except it seems to have "flyback" zener in it.

What would be the correct orientation of the MOSFET over the opamp integrator? Drain toward the output of the opamp?

What would be the saturation voltage?

Also I have used a simulator and it indicated that it "leaked" back in to the gate having a 1M resistor towards -12 volts. I could use a CD4066, but I'd rather have some voltage control option than a binary 0/1.

update:
[image]
this is the actual situation of the integrator, regarding to the voltage divider on the non inverting input and a comparator on the opamp output.

Comment: If the speed requirement isn't too high, also consider an analog switch IC, such as [DG308B](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1866380.pdf) or similar (there are a slew of variants, just search for "analog switch IC".)

Comment: _"except it seems to have "flyback" zener in it"_ That's the body diode. All MOSFETs have them.

Answer (score 3):

That FET will work, but depending on the polarity of the signal you are integrating, you will have to choose an orientation of the FET.

If you have both polarities (i.e. a negative or a positive input), then you can connect two FETs back-back (e.g. join the sources gates and used the two drains as the switch. This will eliminate any parasitic switch path. The FET does not have any leakage towards the gate.

When 'On', the saturation voltage will be 0 -- the FET will behave like a low valued resistor -- of a few ohms.

Note that when you switch the FET(s) off, there will be a charge injection into the 4.7 nF capacitor which will induce a voltage across it. The FET's gate charge is quite high (nC range), so you could get 100's of mV offset. A smaller FET (or a CD4066, or CD4007) might be more appropriate for your application.

Comment: thank you, i updated the question with an image and added the cd4007 in the circuit, since it's a p and n type Fet in one "box" like James mentions below your answer.  i do want to have a voltage controlled option over a 1/0 solution the cd4066 offers, did i wire it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

That "integrator" requires a resistor on the input.

A positive going pulse on the input will cause the integrator's output to ramp downwards in which case an nfet is no good. You can only use an nfet for resetting a positive going output resulting from a negative going input in which case your nfet orientation is correct.

If the input pulses can be of either polarity (positive & negative) resulting in an output of either polarity then use a jfet which contains no body diode.